# Redirect to URL following form input in form submit

Tags: html, forms, redirect

I have this HTML code:

```
<form class="w3-center w3-padding-16" method="get" action="" >
    <input type="search" name="q" placeholder="Buscar en {{categoria}}" autofocus required>
    <input type="submit">                            
</form>
```

My goal is to send the input text to URL. For example if I write "admin" on the textbox the page redirects to "https://example.com/admin"

Answer (score 1):

Add `onsubmit` to the form, and a JS script. Like this:

```js
function redirect(){       
       window.location.href="http://www.example.com/" + document.getElementById("urlInput").value;              
    }
```

```html
<form id="my-form" onsubmit="redirect(); return false" class="w3-center w3-padding-16" method="get" action="" >
        <input id="urlInput" type="search" name="q" placeholder="Buscar en {{categoria}}" autofocus required>
        <input type="submit">         
        </form>
```

Comment: Doesn't work this just add ?q= to the end of the URL